# What can I use as a unique identifier between a node and its translation now that the "tnid" field is no longer available?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

We are upgrading our site from D7 to D8 and a part of this includes sending data out to another resource, specifically, Nodes. When we send data to the 3rd party resource, it's expecting something like

```
[
  { 
    "drupalId": 1,
    "title": "English Node",
    "tnid": 1
  },
  {
    "drupalId": 2,
    "title": "Translated Node",
    "tnid": 1

  }
}
```

This allows the 3rd party resource to store 2 separate nodes and then links them together using the `tnid`, and in this 3rd party resource, the Drupal Id is suppose to be unique. However, in D8, it appears that a node and it's translation has the same Drupal Node Id and there does not exist a 'tnid' value, like it was in D7. I assume this is just the change in how translations work in Drupal 8 now, which brings me to my issue:

What can I use as a unique identifier between a node and its translation now?

In D7, the Node Id was a unique identifier and the tnid was a "link" between a node and its translation. In D8, the Node Id is the "link" between a node and its translation, but what could I use to distinguish a Node from its Translation?

Comment: It depends a little bit what for and how exactly you are using the translation in the end. But nowadays you only need to have a `$node` and then can get its translation depending on the currently selected interface language as easy as `$node = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($node);` and can continue from there.

Comment: I mainly just need a way to upload a node and it's translation to the third party such that 1) there is a unique identifier that distinguishes a Node and its translation (nid in D7) and 2) there is a shared identifier that "links" a node to its translation (tnid in D7)

Comment: In Drupal 8 this is just a langcode, and the node ID. Like https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/203570/15055. You could just foreach through [all available langcodes](https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/get-list-active-languages-drupal-8), too.

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example in **hook_entity_presave** you can do this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function ci_manager_entity_presave($entity) {
  $entity_de = $entity->getTranslation('de');
  $entity_de->getTitle();
}
```

Reference documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/class/Node/9.2.x